# How to know when a menu item has been clicked?

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi, rust, win32gui

I'm using the `winsafe` crate and want to know when a menu item's been clicked in a window.

`flags & MF_MOUSESELECT as u16` should be `1` if so and `0` if not, but it's always `32768` everytime the event is fired, even if it's just from the user hovering a menu item, or even clicking away to make it close.

Why?

```
self.wnd.on().wm(winsafe::co::WM::MENUSELECT, {
  move |params| {
    let wparam = params.wparam;
    let lparam = params.lparam;
    let flags = (wparam >> 16 & 0xffff) as u16;
    let MF_MOUSESELECT = 0x00008000 as u32;
    
    println!("{}", flags & MF_MOUSESELECT as u16);
    // always 32768

    0
  }
});
```

The menu is generated by a resource script which is compiled and embedded in the program:

```
1 MENU
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
{
  POPUP "&File"
  {
    MENUITEM "&Open",  1
    MENUITEM "&Save",  2
  }
  POPUP "&Help"
  {
    MENUITEM "&About",  3
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you also describe how you created the menu.

Comment: @frankenapps I added the relevant resource script.  You can see the full code on Github: https://github.com/GirkovArpa/verpatch-gui-win32

Comment: `MF_MOUSESELECT` is 32768, so `flags & MF_MOUSESELECT as u16` can only be 0 or 32768.

Comment: @Jmb So the correct way to test for the presence of `MF_MOUSESELECT` in the flag sis `(flags & MF_MOUSESELECT as u16) != 0`?

Comment: Yes that's the correct way to test for the presence of a flag in a bitfield.

Comment: In any case, `WM_MENUSELECT` does not tell you when the user actually *invokes* a menu item, `WM_(SYS)COMMAND` tell you that instead. `WM_MENUSELECT` tells you when the user has *selected* (ie, highlighted) a menu item, but has not invoked it yet. Selection and Invocation are not the same thing. And besides, `MF_MOUSESELECT` merely tells you whether the user used the mouse to select the menu item (ie, roll-over hot tracking), but a menu item can also be selected by the keyboard instead (ie, via arrow keys), in which case the `MF_MOUSESELECT` flag will be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle `WM_COMMAND`. There is actually built in functionality for menus. Simply provide the id you specified in your resource file to check when the correponding menu item is clicked.

Replace your event listener with these:

```rust
self.wnd.on().wm_command(co::CMD::Menu, 1, {
  move || {
    println!("Open clicked.")
  }
});

self.wnd.on().wm_command(co::CMD::Menu, 2, {
  move || {
    println!("Save clicked.")
  }
});

self.wnd.on().wm_command(co::CMD::Menu, 3, {
  move || {
    println!("About clicked.")
  }
});
```